# eruby-nxhtml-mode not loading properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, eruby, nxhtml

I have this line in my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(".+\\.html\\.erb$" . eruby-nxhtml-mumamo))
```

however, erb chunks aren't correctly recognised. After I run `M-x eruby-nxhtml-mumamo` everything works like a charm. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `"eruby-nxhtml-mumamo"` to `"eruby-nxhtml-mumamo-mode"`

Comment: Now this is embarrassing! =/ Thanks @crpdm!